# R: Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , as.character(tempcall$exposure)) : undefined columns selected (survival function)

Tags: r, function

I have the following dataset:

```
TTE <- data.frame(
  newid=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B"),
  b6smk=c(0,0,1,1,0,0,0),
  sex=c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1),
  age=c(50,51,52,53,60,61,62),
  e7=c(1,1,2,2,3,2,2),
  starttime=c(-1,0,1,2,-1,0,1),
  fuptime=c(0,1,2,3,0,1,2)
)
```

I am trying to create a function where I change the `exposure`, `numerator` and `denominator` of the inverse probability of weighting (`library(ipw)`) according to the parameters specified in the function:

```
Match_function <- function(TTE,
                           exposure,
                           numerator,
                           denominator){ 
                  ipw.weights = ipwtm(exposure = exposure, family = "survival",
                  numerator = numerator, denominator = denominator,
                  id = newid, tstart = starttime, timevar = fuptime, type = "first",
                  data = as.data.frame(TTE))


}
```

so when I run the function I would like to feed something like the following:

```
Match_function(TTE = TTE, exposure = b6smk, numerator = ~ sex+age, denominator = ~ sex+age+e7)
```

When I do so, I get the error:

```
 Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , as.character(tempcall$exposure)) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

from forums, I have seen that a possible solution might be `eval(substitute(exposure)` but still gives me the same error. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: you call to the function seems to include `method = 'ipw'` and that's not a parameter to your function. Also the code doesn't seem to work even when called outside the function: `ipw.weights = ipwtm(exposure = "A", family = "survival", numerator = ~ sex + age, denominator = ~ . -patient_id -start -end -event -exposure, id = patient_id, tstart = start, timevar = end, type = "first", data = as.data.frame(TTE))` returns an error about start and end lengths. Are you sure you are calling the function correctly?

Comment: Hi @MrFlick I have implemented another dataset in the example and remove the method. This should work :)

Comment: This still doesn't work. You have `id = patient_id` in the function but `patient_id` is no longer in the sample data. Please test your code in a fresh R session before posting to make sure you are getting the exact same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `ipwtm` function seems to use a bit of non-standard evaluation which makes it a bit tricky to use in a function. One method would be to use

```
Match_function <- function(TTE,
                           exposure,
                           numerator,
                           denominator){ 
  eval.parent(substitute(ipwtm(exposure = exposure, family = "survival",
                   numerator = numerator, denominator = denominator,
                   id = newid, tstart = starttime, timevar = fuptime, type = "first",
                   data = as.data.frame(TTE))))
}
```

This uses `substitute()` to grab the values you pass into the function and inject them into the call before evaluating it. An alternative would be a more deliberate building of the call as a list

```
Match_function <- function(TTE,
                           exposure,
                           numerator,
                           denominator){ 
  params <- list(
    exposure = substitute(exposure),
    numerator = numerator, 
    denominator = denominator, 
    family = "survival", 
    type = "first"
  )
  # the alist will preserve these params as symbols
  aparams <- alist(
    id = newid, 
    tstart = starttime, 
    timevar = fuptime,
    data = as.data.frame(TTE)
  )
  do.call("ipwtm", c(params, aparams))
}
```